# friend method from a different namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, friend

I have the following situation. I have a class `foo` inside my own namespace `my_lib`:

```
namespace my_lib{

template<typename T>
class foo{
    T data;
public:
    // blah blah
};

}
```

I am trying to interface to another library that has its own namespace `other_lib`. I am putting this interface inside a `wrapper` namespace in my own `my_lib`. Specifically I for a copy method `my_lib::wrapper::copy` I need access to `my_lib::foo::data` so I need to implement the following:

```
namespace my_lib{
namespace wrapper{

template<typename T>
void copy(const foo<T>& my_foo, other_lib::foo<T>& other_foo)
{
    // copy my_foo.data to other_foo
}

}
}
```

to accomplish this `my_lib::wrapper::copy` method needs to be a friend of `my_lib::foo` class. I can accomplish this by series of forward declarations in `foo.h`

```
// forward declare other_lib::foo
namespace other_lib{
template<typename T>
class foo;
}

namespace my_lib{

// forward declare wrapper::copy
namespace wrapper{
template<typename T>
void copy(const foo<T>& my_foo, other_lib::foo<T>& other_foo);
}

template<typename T>
class foo{
    T data;

    friend void copy(const foo<T>& my_foo, other_lib::foo<T>& other_foo);
public:
    // blah blah
};

}
```

this works but I don't like it. For one thing it adds a lot of stuff to a file that is otherwise unrelated to `other_lib` and `wrapper` namespaces. Also, use of other library is optional in my code, but if someone includes `foo.h` they are going to see all sort of unrelated forward declarations and start to wonder why ...

How can I fix this design?

Comment: why don't you provide iterator access to `foo` so that you won't need any friend functions?

Comment: @rhalbersma I actually thought of that. Two reasons: 1) user does/should not really need any kind of access to internal data 2) iterators for this class are a little bit of hassle and non-trivial (foo is an implementation of CRS sparse matrix format) ... but I guess I could if that's the only other way of doing this

Comment: the interface of `foo` is simply not complete if it needs to grant a `copy` function in some completely unrelated namespace `friend` access. You should either put `copy` inside `foo` (and any other algorithm that users of `foo` need), or provide a minimal set of data access member functions (preferably iterators, not handles to raw data) so that other classes can implement algorithms that work on `foo`.

Comment: @rhalbersma hummmm ... that makes sense.

Comment: formulated it as a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactic tricks to get `friend` to work on other namespaces aside, the proper way is to fix your design. The interface of foo is [**simply not complete**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm) if it needs to grant a `copy()` function in some completely unrelated namespace friend access.

One way to go is to put `copy()` inside `foo` (and any other algorithm that users of foo need). When done right, this leads to a complete and usable class `foo`. E.g. take a look at [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) which has it's own `sort()` member function to take advantage of the list implementation details. However, this can quickly lead to a bloated class interface for `foo` (just look at [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)), so it's not recommended as a general rule.

Alternatively, you could provide a minimal set of data access member functions (preferably iterators, not handles to raw data) so that other classes can implement algorithms that work on `foo`. With a regular container (array, vector etc.) as data representation inside `foo`, this would be my recommendation for general use.

However, since your class `foo` has a tricky sparse matrix representation, you should probably try the algorithms-as-members-approach first.